# How to set JLabel over(in) JLabel in Netbeans only using designer

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, jlabel, designer

Can you tell me please how to put Jlabel over/in another JLabel, but only using 
Netbeans designer.
I make new form, drag 1st JLabek into it, i set icon (background image), and now
I want to drag new JLabel to be shown over 1st JLabel.

I need just a tip now to do this in designer. I have a code for this, but as I said i would like to know is it possible to do with designer

thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, actually you can do it pretty easy with designer BUT you're going to need `JPanel` with null layout

1. Create form using `netbeans` (right click on package, new - `JFrame` Form...
2. Drag and drop panel
3. MOST IMPORTANT: right click on panel from navigator -set Layout -null Layout
4. now you can drag and drop your labels and put it one on another